# erro resolvelivraryimports no xamarin visual studio 2015

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015

sou novo no stack, estava desenvolvendo minhz aplicação de boa e praticamente do nada, recebo um erro ao realizar o deploy no meu projeto .droid no xamarin. o erro está descrito como resolvelibraryimports, já removi, desinstalei e instalei o xamarin e o erro ainda persiste.
criei outro projeto do zero e também, dá o mesmo erro, o que devo fazer?

Answer (score 0):

depois de muito rodar, descobri a causa. aacidentalmente fiz uma dependencia do projeto ios no meu droid, daí não tinha as dlls, daí acidentalmente, fui checar as dependencia, no droid, cliquei com o botao direito no projeto droid, e verifiquei as dependencia. ao tentar desmarcar a selecção da dependencia, recebi um aviso que não poderia desmarcar, daí fui em references no mesmo projeto(droid) removi a referencia clicando com o botão direito , daí resolvi. compilou bonitamente. rs.